# How to formulate the expression of this EM wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, plane-wave

Consider a plane EM wave polarised parallel to the $(Oz)$ axis, this wave propagate in empty space with direction $\overrightarrow{OD}$ in the $(Oxy)$ plane with an angle $ \theta $ from the $(Oz)$ axis
Prove that the expression of this EM wave : $$\overrightarrow{E} = E_0 \cos[2 \pi(\frac{t}{T}-\frac{x \cos(\theta)}{\lambda}-\frac{y \sin(\theta)}{\lambda})] \overrightarrow{e_z}$$ with $T$ the period and $\lambda$ the wave-length
my confusion is why isnt the expression of this EM written in exponential term by definition of a plane EM wave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here we have the general definition of a plane wave:
$$
\bar E = \bar E_0 e^{i(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t)}
$$
(see eq9.49 from Griffith's Introduction to Electrodynamics 4th edition)

Using Euler's formula we can write this as a complex number
$$
\bar E = \bar E_0 \left( \cos(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t) + i \sin(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t)\right)
$$

The real component of this complex vector ($\bar E \in \mathbb C^3$) is just the function
$$
\Re(\bar E) = \vec E_0 \cos(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t)
$$
and since $\cos$ is an even function we can always write the above as
$$
\Re(\bar E) = \vec E_0 \cos( \omega t - \vec k \cdot \vec r )
$$

Since $c = f\lambda$ and $ f = \frac{1}{T}= \frac{\omega}{2\pi}$ then $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$. Further $\vec k$ defines the direction of propagation and has magnitude  $|\vec k | = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$. Thus we may reduce the above to
$$
\Re(\bar E) = \vec E_0 \cos\left[ 2\pi\left(\frac{t}{T} - \frac{\hat k}{\lambda} \cdot \vec r \right)\right]
$$
Finally, since the direction of propagation is in the the $xy$-plane, then $\hat k \cdot \vec r = \cos(\theta) x + \sin(\theta)y$ where $\theta$ is measured from the $x$-axis. Including the fact that the direction of propagation is always perpendicular to the axis of polarization, $\vec E_0 \cdot \vec k = 0$ (also eq9.50), then
$$
\Re(\bar E) = E_0 \hat z \cos\left[ 2\pi\left(\frac{t}{T} - \frac{\cos(\theta) x + \sin(\theta)y}{\lambda} \right)\right]
$$
QED.

Comment: Infinite thanks